Objects associated with enums in Swift lack ObservableObject and @Published wrappers, preventing state changes from updating the UI
I have a MainViewModel that holds an array of enums with associated objects. However, when I use this in a SwiftUI view, the variable loses its @Published wrapper, and the UI doesn't update or get notified of changes. How can I preserve the @Published status of the variable?
Here's my code look like:
// Enum with associated types
enum ViewType: Hashable, Identifiable {
    case .a(ViewModelA)
    case .b(ViewModelB)
    case .c(ViewModelC)
}

// classes used in associated types
class ViewModelA: ObservableObject {
    @Published var listIndex: Int = 1
    //some other properties
}

class ViewModelB: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = "hello"
     //some other properties
}

class ViewModelC: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false
     //some other properties
}

// then I create an array in my mainViewModel
// to use in my SwiftUI view
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewTypeArray: [ViewType] = [] // add items to it based on the backend response (assume I have 4 items)
}


// then I use the viewModel in my view
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject viewModel: MainViewModel

    init(viewModel: MainViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(viewModel.viewTypeArray) { view in
            case .a(let viewModelA):
               // I display something
               // I loose the ObservableObject wrapper
               // then I lose the connection to @Published wrapper properties ex: `listIndex`
               // and no ui updates will trigger here
            case .b(let viewModelB):
               // I display something
               // I loose the ObservableObject wrapper
               // then I lose the connection to @Published properties ex: `name`
               // and no ui updates will trigger here
            case .c(let viewModelC):
               // I display something
               // I loose the ObservableObject wrapper
               // then I lose the connection to @Published properties ex: `isOn`
               // and no ui updates will trigger here
        }
    }
}

I tried using an ObservableObject wrapper for each child ViewModel (e.g., ViewModelA, ViewModelB) to maintain a direct connection with the view, but this didn't work. I want to use an enum with associated types, along with @ObservableObject and @Published wrappers, to ensure that changes properly update the SwiftUI view.

@ObservableObject is put in the child view

You'd better choose a design where you have an enum which mutually contains the view state of each view, e.g.enum ViewState { case ViewStateA; case ViewStateB; case ViewStateC }, and then one ViewModel which contains the composed logic of each view. And then also use one View which internally uses a switch to show either view. ViewModels (and MVVM) do not compose the way you did in your code.

You can use a wrapper to selectively expose specific @Published properties.
struct PropertyWrapper<T: ObservableObject, Content: View>: View {
    @ObservedObject private var value: T
    private var content: (T) -> Content

    init(value: T, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {
        self.value = value
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        content(value)
    }
}

and then use it as below ex: in case .b
 ForEach(viewModel.viewTypeArray) { view in 
            switch view {
                case .a(let viewModelA):
                   // I display something
                   // I loose the ObservableObject wrapper
                   // then I lose the connection to @Published wrapper properties ex: `listIndex`
                   // and no ui updates will trigger here
                case .b(let viewModelB):
                   PropertyWrapper(value: viewModelB) { object in 
                     Text(object.name) // this should update the UI properly when `name` updates
                   }
                case .c(let viewModelC):
                   // I display something
                   // I loose the ObservableObject wrapper
                   // then I lose the connection to @Published properties ex: `isOn`
                   // and no ui updates will trigger here
            }
        }

I hope this work as expected. have fun.
